# Bars on screen with Windows 7, but no problems with Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, display

I'm using GRUB to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7. 
When I boot Ubuntu, no problems:

[image]

but when I boot Windows:

[image]

I tried to find what's going on with my computer,
but I don't know what to say with my computer's status. 
Sorry if my English is poor.

and now, I can't boot normally and automatically booted with safe-mode.
I'm guessing it's because of my graphic card driver, but it's just a guess.
I downloaded graphic driver on nvidea web site, but I can't reinstall cuz i can't boot normally, but safe-mode.
If i uninstall gtx 660 graphic driver and reboot, problem disappear.
But if i reboot without uninstalling my graphic driver, the problem occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

Not a for sure answer, but at a guess, its likely a display resolution settings issue (based on the bar pattern).

A bit of light searching suggests that the GTX 660 drivers are not great. That said, you may want to ensure that your monitor is using driver made for it. Apparently, the GTX 660 drivers may not play well with Windows generic monitor drivers (you would have to install the new monitor drivers in safe mode, before reinstalling the GTX 660 drivers).

You may also want to take a look at your GRUB settings and see if you can detect any problems with incorrect resolutions that might be associated with Windows there.